# git fsck -- full gives no problems but can't push upstream

Tags: git

I have a project of about 7000 files, of which I'm trying to add and commit about 4000 for an initial push upstream

running

```
 git fsck --full
```

returns with no errors
but when I do a

```
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
git push origin master
```

I get an error like this

```
fatal: loose object 890b67d9a81c0061176d5a9a061cc6437eac283d (stored in .git/objects/89/0b67d9a81c0061176d5a9a061cc6437eac283d) is corrupt
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@xxxxxxx'
```

the crazy thing is that the loose object referenced is different each time I run that push command.

and very very occasionally it will actually start pushing the objects upstream before failing midway with this message

```
Counting objects: 4551, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4168/4168), done.
fatal: loose object c839cf225383c94e4bb2234fca9f9b8b2d645cde (stored in .git/objects/c8/39cf225383c94e4bb2234fca9f9b8b2d645cde) is corrupt
fatal: early EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@xxxxxxxx'
```

I'm at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be:

- a permission issue (ACL too restrictive on  `.git/object/...`)
- a handle issue (`.git/objects/c8/39cf225383c94e4bb2234fca9f9b8b2d645cde` somehow already locked by another process)
- a corruption issue (in which case you need to check if that file is present in another branch (or simply readable on `master`), and copy it in `.git/objects/c8`)